# Ethereum verify transaction using ecrecover returns incorrect address

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development

** STILL NOT SOLVED **

I'm trying to verify a message, however the ecrecover function is returning the incorrect address: 0x828c50fDeE9160C76EE160C9d8e9D4bc4Cc3D591

```
function verify(bytes32 message, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public pure returns (address) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, message));
    address signer = ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s);
    return signer;
}
```

Message = "test"

Message hash = 0x9c22ff5f21f0b81b113e63f7db6da94fedef11b2119b4088b89664fb9a3cb658

v = 28

r =  0x1e97a4e505996ba54c0003a79281e5c714afe5b93aa867d87a50e6d0c1bb5c81

s = 0x68cf3bbc7afb18e412d68d50c444ba046eea8adc28fa72cda5c12a4199e1b843

Address/Expected result = 0x70b224FF8089D40e4d91331f8284Bb8Ab9877E4B

I am using Ganache-cli.
I have tested in Remix and it works however when I run using ganache and metamask I do not get correct answer.
Not sure what is going wrong???
Many Thanks in advance.

EDIT (front-end)

```
var payload = "test"
// hash of message
var testData = web3.utils.sha3("test")

// ethereum address 
var address = accounts[0]

var signature = web3.eth.sign(testData,address)


signature = signature.slice(2)
console.log(signature)
var r = `0x${signature.slice(0, 64)}`
var s = `0x${signature.slice(64, 128)}`
var v = web3.utils.toDecimal(signature.slice(128, 130)) 

const response = await contract.methods.verify(testData, v, r, s).call()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your message was signed without the prefix. The message hash that you wrote is the hash of 'test' without the prefix, so use only message without the prefix in the contract. It works in remix.

if message is the hash of 'test' use this:

```
function verify(bytes32 message, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public pure returns (address) {
    address signer = ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    return signer;
}
```

if message is the string 'test' use this

```
function verify(string message, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public pure returns (address) {
    bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message));
    address signer = ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s);
    return signer;
}
```

Comment: Removed the prefix in the contract and still not getting the same address. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help

Comment: I edited the answer to show how I did it in remix. Let me know.

Comment: Note that if message is 'test' then you should use 'string' instead of 'bytes32'

Comment: Still not working. I am using your first answer, passing in web3.utils.sha3("test") as my first parameter. Do I have to cast this to bytes32 first?

Comment: A comment here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/392 says that test rpc needs the prefix I originally put in. Maybe remix gives behaves like geth?

Comment: can you show me what are you doing?, this works well for me. I am using remix and the first option I gave you in my answer

Comment: I have edited my question to show my front-end as well

Comment: I get the correct answer as well in remix. It must be a metamask or ganache-cli issue??

Comment: I do not know, you may want to see the transaction data and see that the data match the variables message,r, s, and v. In any case if it works in remix, that is the way to go. If the answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Comment: How do I see the transaction data? I need it to work using ganache

Comment: when you send the transaction you get a txhash, use that to get the receipt and check the data, (or input) field. The data first 4 bytes are the signature of the function the remaining should be a concatenation of the arguments that you are sending to the function in the same order as they appear in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you need to first hash the message payload before rehashing it again with the signature prefix.

Here is a fully functional example for you get to get all intricacies related to signature operations. It runs with `web3 1.0` and should be executed with `nodejs`.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const utils = require('ethereumjs-util');

// The actual message to sign
const payload = "test";
// First hash the payload (equivalent to Solidity's keccack256)
const hashedPayload = Web3.utils.soliditySha3(payload);
// Then add the prefix and rehash (equivalent to Solidity's keccack256)
const paddedMessage = Web3.utils.soliditySha3("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hashedPayload);
// Remove the '0x' hex prefix
const message = hashedPayload.substring(2, hashedPayload.length);
// Reeconde the message as a buffer
const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(message, 'hex');
console.log('message: ', message);

// Load signature parameters
const v = 28;
const r = '0x1e97a4e505996ba54c0003a79281e5c714afe5b93aa867d87a50e6d0c1bb5c81';
const s = '0x68cf3bbc7afb18e412d68d50c444ba046eea8adc28fa72cda5c12a4199e1b843';

// Expected signer address
const expected = '0x70b224FF8089D40e4d91331f8284Bb8Ab9877E4B'.toLowerCase();

// Same as Solidity's ecrecover function
const pub = utils.ecrecover(messageBuffer, v, r, s);
// Convert the output public key to address
const recoveredAddress = '0x' + utils.pubToAddress(pub).toString('hex');

// Print the result and show it works
console.log('recovered address: ', recoveredAddress);
console.log('success: ', recoveredAddress === expected);
```

Note that the Buffer/Hex part could still be simplified, but this should already get you going.

Comment: You say my issue is that I first hash the message payload before rehashing it again with the signature prefix however don't you do the same thing in your example?

Comment: You indeed need to hash the message once, then add the prefix and rehash this concatenated output. I did this in the code provided, assigning the output to paddedMessage. Is this more clear now?

Comment: I realise that I made a typo in the initial answer, just fixed it and it should be clear now.

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/27297969/25290626/14f00a96-268c-11e7-925f-6c5c1b4be485.png

Comment: diagram linked above says that for testrpc you do not need to prepend that prefix

Answer (score 0):

Using [ethereumjs-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-util) npm package. Most likely you are not passing correct `v,r,s` values:

```
import * as util from "ethereumjs-util";
// define the signature. maybe you sent through request
const { v, r, s } = util.fromRpcSig(signature);

const response = await contract.methods.verify(testData, v, r, s).call()
```